# How to request a user to authorize an app to access a Google Drive file using the API

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have a web application and a Google Docs add-on that work together.  The Docs add-on passes the web application the Google Drive file id of the Doc it's currently running in.

My web application needs to be able to be able to access/download the file content.  I want the web application to use the drive.file scope, so that would require the user to authorize the web application access to the file in Google Drive.

I haven't found any APIs which let me request the user authorize the web app permission to a known file id.  I could use the File Picker API, but then the user has to find the file in their Drive (annoying user experience given we already know the file and prone to errors).

Is there any way we can just redirect the user to a Google Drive URL where it asks them to confirm they want to open the file with my web app?  Or to preselect the file in the File Picker?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think you completely understand how scopes work.

The is no way to request permission for just a single file id. Scopes are all or nothing.  If you have read only access then you have read only access to all of the files on the users drive account.  Same for write access.

Now lets look at [Scopes#Drive](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#drive)

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file    See, edit, create, and delete only the specific Google Drive files you use with this app

If you request authorization of the user using the drive.file scope.  It will allow your application to create files on the users drive account, and access those files which your application created and only those files.

So there is no way to get access to only a single file on a users drive account.  If you want access to a file on the users account that wasn't created by your app then your going to have to use drive.readonly or drive. Depending upon if you want read or write access.

Comment: When the user signs up for the web application, the web app requests the drive.file scope as part of our SSO.  The documents they use the add-on with aren't created through the web app (we're in an educational setting, so may have been created through assignments in Google Classroom, etc.), so the web app doesn't have permission to the document.  If we had the web app use the file picker it would grant our app permission for that file, but then the user has to find it in their Google Drive when we already know what file we need.

Comment: All of the above sounds right to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible with the exposed Drive API. The most restrictive scope for your app in that regard is `drive.file`, which will allow your app to access any file that the user selects with the Picker, or that you create.

The way Google seems to implement this is that when first loading the Google Picker UI, they send an interim token that allows the picker to do most of the work it need (list all files, but not generate thumbnails because [that's currently broken and only works with at least the full `drive.readonly` scope](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/208855070)).

When the user selects a file in the picker, it will send a couple of requests to a private Google API (with both the OAuth token and the interim token) that will grant your app's Client ID access to that file. After that, you are free to use any methods you like to edit the file. However, you will need the user's first interaction to send that request to the Google API in order for Google to allowlist your application to access that file id.

There is no other documented way at present to do that. We are going through Google Verification just because one of our features is to import a Drive file by URL. We explored but currently (early 2024) there is no public way of doing that without full read-only access.